# Why does Whoops look different on my Laravel sometime?

Tags: laravel, whoops

I am playing with a non-standard Laravel application that I have built without the template (`laravel new`). I am quite new to this framework but I noticed that Whoops can take different shapes:

A minimal version:

[image]

The standard Whoops skin:

[image]

Or the tweaked orange skin:

[image]

What does influence these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a duplicate whoops package installed, an old one or you have the old whoops css files somewhere.

The orange colors are the old styles

See this: https://github.com/vladshcherbin/whoops-orange-laravel-colors

As for the 'minimal' picture you posted, if you look at:

`yourwebsitedirectory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/500.blade.php`

you'll see the text shown in the 'minimal' screenshot you posted so it's definitely Laravel's own 500 error page and not Whoops. (which confirms its not a 404 as well)

Comment: Oh thanks searching "orange grey whoops" on Google did not give me relevant results. I indeed had two versions of Whoops installed. What about this minimal red-ish whoops theme?

Comment: What about the minimal one?

Comment: In my question I have included 3 images. You answered my question about the latter ones, not the first one. Do you have any idea why I am seeing this one instead of the second one?

Comment: Oh I see. Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: It is Laravel 5.7, I only have `laravel/framework` and `laravel/tinker` in my `composer.json`

Comment: I'm not quite sure actually... Is `APP_DEBUG` set to true in `config/app.php` ?

Comment: Yes it is otherwise I would have seen an error `500`.

Comment: I think the first one must be Laravel's own... it doens't look like something from Whoops. Now why Laravels one would be showing and not Whoops all the time I don't know.

Comment: Yes.. if you look at `yourwebsitedirectory/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/500.blade.php` you'll see the text shown in the 'minimal' screenshot you posted. The first is definitely Laravel's own 500 error page (which confirms its not a 404 as well)

Comment: Except the `Woops` word I would say. But you found the reason why I was seeing the red-ish error. When I removed Whoops, I actually removed both installation. Whoops has to be installed separately it seems.

Comment: Read the comment I just posted, I have located that template file with the word 'whoops' as you mention inside Laravel default files

Comment: I would suggest to remove all comments there and update your post with the final answer. Does it sounds good to you?

Comment: @nowox I added to my answer but I don't feel removing comments is neccessary.